# objective c: call method in masterViewController from detailViewController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail, method-call, detailview

I am using x-codes Master-detail template. I have a button in the detailView that has its action also in the detailViewController. Within this action method i need to call a method that is in the masterViewController. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the reference of the masterViewController. use the delegate pattern.

Init your detailViewController with this type of function :

```
-(id)initWithDelegate:(id)deleg;
```

with protocol :

```
 -(id)initWithDelegate:(id<myProtocol>)deleg;
```

and had in your .h of detailViewController

```
id delegate;
```

with protocol :

```
id<myProtocol> delegate;
```

then in the .m of detail :

```
-(id)initWithDelegate:(id)deleg
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
       delegate = deleg
    }
    return self;
}
```

then in your function

```
   -(IBAction)actionOfmyButton
    {
        if(delegate != nil && [delegate respondToSelector:@selector(functionFoo:)])
        {
           [delegate functionFoo:myArgumentsIfnecessary];
        }
    }
```

Good luck ^^ !

Comment: I now have the initWithDelegate:() method listed in my detailViewcontroller.h and defined in detailViewcontroller.m. I have also added the code for my action. I am however not sure what I'm supposed to do with the rest of the code u have provided there.. some help please..

Comment: if(delegate != nil && [delegate respondToSelector:@selector(functionFoo:)])
        {
           [delegate functionFoo:myArgumentsIfnecessary];
        }

Comment: inside your MasterViewController you need to add the function -(void)functionFoo:(thetypeofyourVariable)yourVariable) and automaticly the functionFoo will be call by your detailViewController in the MasterViewController. It's called the delegate Pattern. hope it's helping you.

Comment: Could you check the answer please !

Comment: hey, I didn't get the chance to check that code out, the project I was working on was temporarily put aside and I have no access to it. Never the less, i will create a simple app that mimics the situation and then test your suggestion. Thank you for that

Comment: played around with the code, and finally got it working. I think this master-detail template in the future should allow us to do something like [self.masterViewController  myMethodInMaster] from the detailViewController by default. Thanks for the help, learnt something really useful

Comment: No ! try to avoid that. Because you create dependance between both objects. Imagine that one day you will change the masterViewController class to another. It will be complicated. Good luck

Comment: i very much understand what you mean. I was quite new to a number of things in object oriented programming when I asked the question, and I'm still learning